# jQuery addClass() not working in PHP which includes header.php which loads jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, addclass

As the title, addClass() does not work in this php file.

http://wafflemaker.kr/ykrf/forum2011/forum2011.php

```
    <h3 class="fs12 read-more-toggle ti20">Read more</h3>
    <script type="text-javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.read-more-content').addClass('hide');
            // Set up the toggle.
            $('.read-more-toggle').on('click', function() {
              $(this).next('.read-more-content').toggleClass('hide');
            }); 
    }); 
    </script>       
    <div class="read-more-content pd20" style="border: 1px dotted #444444;">
        <p class="fs12 al_justify">Recent years, natural and men-made disasters are frequently  attacking almost all around the world. Disasters occured in our three countries recently are driving more and more people' s attention to the precaution and emergence responses.</p>
```

class "hide" means display:none, and it is well defined in the CSS.
At the top of forum2011.php, it includes header2.php which has the line

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js?ver=3.2.1"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://wafflemaker.kr/ykrf/js/ui/jquery.effects.core.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://wafflemaker.kr/ykrf/js/ui/jquery.ui.core.min.js"></script>
```

jQuery functions that apply to elements in header2.php work well, but not at all to elements in forum2011.php.

Is this because jQuery script tag in one page does not reach the page which included it?
also, now I already have $(document).ready() in header2.php. Is it a problem to use another $(document).ready() in forum2011.php as well?

Comment: How specifically does this fail?  The includes being done server-side are of no concern to JavaScript, it only sees the resulting client-side DOM.  Is there an error on the JavaScript console?  When you debug this, does that code execute at all?  Does the jQuery selector find the elements you expect it to find?  Is the class added when you expect the DOM?  Is the click handler's selector finding the elements you expect?  Is it being invoked?  Please debug this and see if you can narrow down the problem at all.

Answer (score 1):

`type` attribute of the `script` tag should be `text/javascript` not `text-javascript`. Currently since  browser doesn't recognize the specified `type`, it doesn't interpret the `script` tag's content as JavaScript. In HTML5 documents, the `type` attribute is optional and defaults to `text/javascript`, so you can also remove the attribute.

> Is it a problem to use another `$(document).ready()`?

No, it isn't.

Comment: Oops.. I made a very stupid mistake. Thank you. And actually I was more curious about the second question. Thank you very much.